# Modify depth-first search to work within a specific radius

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, depth-first-search

Suppose you have a weighted graph. Starting from a random node, how can you use depth first search (modify the iterative algorithm that uses an explicit stack) to check which nodes exist within a certain weight radius? (Are reachable from this node in a specific weight.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we use the type `Node` to denote a node in the graph. In the simplest case, `Node` could be just an integer (`int`).

Normally, we use an explicit stack of type `Node`. In your case, we can use a stack of type `pair<Node,int>` where `pair<A,B>` is the type of a pair, and the `int` represents the distance from your starting point to this `Node`.

Suppose we are now at `Node` `u` with distance `d`. For an adjacent `Node` `v`, let `w` be the weight of the edge `uv`. Then just push `pair(v, d+w)` to the stack. Initially, push `pair(v0, 0)` where `v0` is the starting point of the depth first search.